# Search document even when some fields are missing in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search student based on `centerId`, `courseId` and `batchId`. For example i have student data as below.

```
{
"s1":{
"name":alex,
"centerId":"N001",
"courseId":"ncjava",
"batchId":"nb1"},

"s2":{
"name":John,
"centerId":"N001",
"courseId":"nc02",
"batchId":"ncb2"},

"s3":{
"name":David,
"centerId":"N001",
"courseId":"ncjava",
}
}
```

Now i want to search student where `centerId`,`courseId` and `batchId` matches and even want students that have matching `centerId` and `courseId` but where `batchId` is missing. I wrote below query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {"must": [
     {
    "match": {
        "centerId":"N001"
    }},
    { "match": {
       "courseId": "ncjava"
    }}
    ],
        "should":[
            {
        "match": {
           "batchId": "nb1"
        }
    }
    ]
    }
}
```

}

This query returns me all the student that matches with `centerId` and `courseId`. But it also returns me students who have different 'batchId'. I only want student when `batchId` is matched or it does not exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add query terms which are "bool", in order to make "or" logic like you want. `batchId = X OR batchId is missing` can be represented with a should expression (and `batchId is missing` with a `must_not` and `exists`), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "centerId": "N001"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "courseId": "ncjava"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "batchId": "nb1"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "batchId"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can consider `must` like "and", and `should` like "or" (though more flexible than boolean or), and `must_not` as boolean "not". So, the above query means something like `centerId == N001 AND courseId == ncjava AND (batchId == nb1 OR NOT exists batchId)`.

In this particular context, `minimum_should_match` actually isn't required (the default behavior is already what you want), but since the behavior is different in different contexts, I like to include it explicitly, in case the query is edited in an unexpected way in the future (then the behavior of the `should` will remain the same despite the changed context). `minimum_should_match` of 1 means that at least 1 of the `should` clauses must match.

Here's the docs for each of these components:

[bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
[exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)
[minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)

Comment: sorry @dshockley your query give me this exception `[must] query malformed, no start_object after query name`

Comment: I did required changes and it works fine now. Can u please explain me above query

Comment: Why `"minimum_should_match": 1` is used

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed a bool. I've updated to fix that, and also updated the answer with more explanation.